# Intercept gmails/outlook incoming email for further inspection

Tags: gmail-api, outlook-restapi

I want my code to be executed(hotsted as API) whenever there is an incoming email in gmail/outlook(free version).
I want to Reader Header/body/subject information and either automatically reply back or move the email to Trash folder depending on the logic.

I am looking for Event Driven solution as first preference.

Is this possible ? Any pointers to documentation or if someone has developed similar solution is helpful

Comment: Is there a reason that [Gmail filters](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en) aren't suitable for this?

Comment: I want to run custome Code and connect to SQL database . in short quite a bit of custom Code.